# Conditions for an element of a group to normalize a subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

This question is from Abstract Algebra, 3rd Edition: Dummit & Foote

> (a) Prove that a subgroup $N$ of $G$ is normal iff. $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ for all $g\in G$.
>   
>  (b) Let $G=GL(2,\Bbb Q)$, let $N$ be the subgroup of upper triangular matrices with integer entries and $1$'s on the diagonal, and let $g$ be the diagonal matrix with entries $2,1$. Show that $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ but $g$ does not normalize $N$.

(a) First of all, $N\lhd G$ iff. for all $g\in G$, $gNg^{-1}=N$. This implies $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$.
To show that $N$ is normal if $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ for all $g\in G$, I have to show that $N\subseteq gNg^{-1}$

we claim that for all $n\in N$, $g\in G$ there exists $n'\in N$ such that $gng^{-1}=n'$. Then $n=g^{-1}n'(g^{-1})^{-1}$. Since $g$ is arbitrary, **can I argue that $N\subseteq gNg^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$ in this way?**

Another way of showing this is:

$N\lhd G$ iff. for all $g\in G$, $gNg^{-1}=N$ iff. for all $g$, $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$.
**Can I argue that $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ implies $gNg^{-1}=N$ because there is a bijection between them, so they are of the same size?**: $N\rightarrow gNg^{-1}$ as defined by $n\mapsto gng^{-1}$.

(b) $N=\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & a\\0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}, a\in \Bbb Z\}$. $g=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}$. Let $n\in N$

so $gng^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}2 & 0\\0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & a\\0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1/2 & 0\\0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2a\\0 & 1\\\end{pmatrix}\in N$. **How come  does $g$ not normalize $N$?**

Answer (score 0):

You have to show that $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ but that $g^{-1}Ng\not\subseteq N$. In general
$$g^{-1}ng=\pmatrix{1/2&0\\0&1}\pmatrix{1&a\\0&1}\pmatrix{2&0\\0&1}
=\pmatrix{1&a/2\\0&1}.$$

Comment: Interesting... What about part (a)? Are some (or all) of my arguments invalid?

Comment: @hellotinfish  The statement $N=gNg^{-1}$ is equivalent to both $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ and $g^{-1}Ng\subseteq N$ holding.

Comment: I mean, I have to show that $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ for all $g$ solely implies $gNg^{-1}= N$ in (a). Could you see if there's anything wrong about my arguments?

Comment: @hellotinfish I'm sorry, I couldn't follow your argument for (a). I do suggest rewriting $N\subseteq gNg^{-1}$ as $g^{-1}Ng\subseteq N$, though.